# question about bundle identifier status Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hey guys I am pretty new to the Xcode and swift, and so far I am implementing the remote notification by APN by referring to the tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/11395893-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started. And I am stuck on the step of renaming the Bundle Identifier to something unique. In the signing & capabilities session, I tried to directly change the bundle identifier of my `project to com.f20cmsc435.ifttt`. However, I encounter a status warning:

```
No profiles for 'com.f20cmsc435.ifttt' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.f20cmsc435.ifttt'
```

. Does anyone know how to resolve this error? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new provisioning profile against the new bundle identifier. Then you will able to build. And also you  need to create push certificate also. Bundle Identifier, Provisioning Profile and Push certificates are tightly coupled in iOS.